# Generating 100 unique 6 char string and corresponding SAH3

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have to generate 100 unique 6 char string and corresponding SAH3.
To generate 100 unique 6 char string I am using `urandom` as follows...

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 6  | head -n 100
```

To generate sha3 hash I am using the following command...

```
 printf "yellow" | openssl dgst -sha3-256
```

I am not getting how to integrate these to commands such that, the output will be as follows...

```
yellow 72dd9e237feb9877f9fa25470fcdd0d0c876a090c734de8be1059adea209ae29
foobar 09234807e4af85f17c66b48ee3bca89dffd1f1233659f9f940a2b17b0b8c6bc5
...
```

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't it be as simple as: ```cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 6  | head -n 10 | while read str junk; do openssl dgst -sha3-256 <<<"${str}"; done```
Obviously it could/should be converted from the one-liner.

Comment: @vgersh99, note that the herestring `<<<"$str"` adds a newline, altering the value being digested.

Comment: There's no guarantee that this will produce 100 unique strings. It's *unlikely*, but `tr` could output something like `yellowfoobaryellowbanana...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest while read line

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 6  | head -n 100 |
while IFS= read -r line; do
     echo "$line $(printf "%s" "$line" | openssl dgst -sha3-256 | cut -d' ' -f2-)"
done
```

I would recommend to re-read a basic introduction to shell scripting. Here is one https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide .

Comment: Why produce a digest of an [:xdigit:] string? Produce a digest of binary stream directly instead

Comment: `printf` doesn't need to be inside the command substitution; `printf "%s %s\n" "$line" $(echo "$line" | openssl ...)` will suffice. (It's also good practice not to use parameter expansion in the format string unless you plan for the result to contain `%` escapes.)

Comment: `echo "$line" | openssl` will not suffice as it's different string. `printf "asdfgh"` will print just that "asdfgh" but `echo "asdfgh"` will print "asdfgh\n", and that's not the same thing. `Sha3("asdfgh")=759f11...`, `Sha3("asdfgh\n")=011832...`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add all the random 6 char strings to one long string containing all the little strings:

```
allStrings=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 6  | head -n 100)
echo "$allStrings"" "
> qnLRFn fTzC6f dPhYf2 ...
```

and then iterate over all strings in that long string:

```
for shortString in $allStrings; do
    echo -n $shortString #Print without newline at the end
    echo $shortString | openssl dgst -sha3-256 | sed 's/(stdin)= //g' #use sed to remove info string of openssl
done
```